# Using LimeSurvey, how can I make it go right to a survey on the home page

Tags: php, limesurvey

I don't know anything about PHP, but I'm using LimeSurvey on my site.  I want index.php to go immediately to a certain survey ID.  I don't want it so the user has to put the survey ID on the URL.  I have no idea how to do this.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You've probably worked something out by now, but I had the same requirement. I used a quick & dirty .htaccess as follows - change the survey ID to match the one you want to use.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php?sid=12345
```